# Sqlite database file location changes when Application gets installed

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

i am in a big trouble and it is because of my Sqlite database file is being stored in **User/AppData/Local/Virtual Store/Program file** directory rather then In program Files. During creating installer i had set the default installation path as **C:\Program Files**. can any one tell me that how can i store the database file in program file. Due to this issue my application is re-creating database everytime when application is opened by the user because it is not able to find the database file. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Even though you want to change it I would suggest you to hold back for a minute and re-think. Let's say you even hard-code the path or make a configuration that specifies that file's location. Then assume your end-user doesn't have any partition labeled `C:`, then all of this wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you pass information of path in `app.config` configuration file. example

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="dbpath" value="c:/program files" />
  </appSettings>
```

and read path from config.

```
public static string GetConfigurationValue()
{
    if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbpath"]!=null)
      return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbpath"];
    else 
      return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: i want to know that when would the dbpath would be empty ? means at which point.?

Comment: @anmolrathod - that is case if you remove value from appSetting....its just check to stop your application crashing in case someone remove entry fro config file...

Comment: i tried the above code and realized that the path is hard coded and in my case the installation path depends upon the user selection because i am giving option to change the default one.

Comment: @anmolrathod - please do accept/upvote answer if it works for you

Comment: @anmolrathod- what is not working ... have you added path in configuration ?? if you have use select dynamically ...I suggest you store path in some file which is local to you exe ..that will do work for you

Comment: Pranay Rana- what i am doing is that i will move the database file from that Virtual Store directory and move to the application installed location. Which in end i think would my solve the problem. What you think about it Pranay Rana ?

Comment: @anmolrathod - that is good way ..I do like that in my production application keep my sqllite file in same folder as my application install and ask it to pick up from there ...

Comment: Pranay Rana- i want to ask you that would it be any kind of risk for losing records from database after the application gets updated.? because i had to implement that thing too.

Comment: @anmolrathod - till you are not creating any new database by code ..there is no issue ..when you release patch or release application next time it better not to release database ...and do check if database file is already exists or not ...if exists do not overwrite it and if exists do not create new database file

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question. I am also having an issue with creating the file in the bin/debug of a UWP app, running sqlite EF core. This is how I found a solution.

What I found was to avoid the program directory entirely and the permission issues, in my case. There is a great handler for these types of situations, where the sqlite file is always created in the same spot, however rather obscure, with a guid directory

```
C:\Users\(me)\AppData\Local\Packages\7ef58417-7e0c-4365-a1b8-0bdb6ea01c64_mdkyq2wgmdezj\LocalState
```

This checks if the sqlite db file exists and creates it if not, with EF core creating the tables. Then I api call to populate the accounts table.

```
            using (var dbi = new TimeTrackerUwpContext())
            {
                var databaseCreator = (RelationalDatabaseCreator)dbi.Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>();
                if (!databaseCreator.Exists())
                    await databaseCreator.EnsureCreatedAsync();
                else
                    dbi.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM [Account];");
                var acc = GetAccoutsToSync().Result;
                if (acc.Count == 0)
                    return;
                await dbi.Account.AddRangeAsync(acc);
                await dbi.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
```

I also had to make a Class Library to run EF core the way I wanted to, which has the models that 
    await databaseCreator.EnsureCreatedAsync();
uses.

[image]

I hope this helps.